# How can I override a JS function inside another function?

Tags: javascript, shared-libraries, sharepoint-2013

Am in a position of overriding a js function which is inside another function.

For example:

```
function parentMethod(){
   function someOtherMethod(){
      alert("Am someone")
   }
   function childMethod(){
      alert("Am Child")
   }
   childMethod()
}

childMethod = function(){
      alert("Am Child New")
   }
```

Actually I want to override a sub function of the out-of-the-box js scirpt provided by sharepopint.If I override `parentMethod` it is working correctly but it will produce 1300 lines of code duplication since we are actually overriding one of the many available functions.

How can I achieve it without code duplication.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The childMethod you mentioned is not accessible outside the scope of the parent unless the parent function is defined properly i.e. the childMethod you are trying to access is not linked to the parent. e.g.

```
var parentMethod = function (){
   this.someOtherMethod = function (){
      alert("Am someone")
   }
   this.childMethod = function(){
      alert("Am Child")
   }
}
```

There is no proper way of achieving this with the current state of the parent class however I made a working fiddle for the sake of a working example. https://jsfiddle.net/eaqnnvkz/

```
var parentMethod = {
  someOtherMethod: function() {
    alert("Am someone")
  },

  childMethod: function() {
    alert("Am Child")
  }
};

parentMethod.childMethod();
parentMethod.childMethod = function() {
  alert("Am Child New")
};

parentMethod.childMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). The problem is, actually the parent method is not written by me. It is sharepoint Out-of-box Script file which am referring to. So I cannot change the parent method.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, unless the script is written to attach the sub-function to an accessible scope, it can't be overridden selectively. A function inside a function, by default, is not individually accessible.

A rather hackish way this might be attempted would be to get the source of `parentMethod()`, via `parentMethod.toString()`, and then to use a regular expression to replace the child method, and then to replace the original version of the function with the altered version using `eval()`. This is likely not a long-term solution and I would personally discourage it, but it would theoretically accomplish the requested effect.