# Can I override a function that has been declared in another function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, particles.js

I am learning JavaScript and I want to use particlesJS for my project, but the problem is there is a function in the library I want to customize but I don't know how

the function is this code written in line 752 and i want to overwrite it in my own javascript

```js
pJS.fn.modes.pushParticles = function(nb, pos){

    pJS.tmp.pushing = true;

    for(var i = 0; i < nb; i++){
      pJS.particles.array.push(
        new pJS.fn.particle(
          pJS.particles.color,
          pJS.particles.opacity.value,
          {
            'x': pos ? pos.pos_x : Math.random() * pJS.canvas.w,
            'y': pos ? pos.pos_y : Math.random() * pJS.canvas.h
          }
        )
      )
      if(i == nb-1){
        if(!pJS.particles.move.enable){
          pJS.fn.particlesDraw();
        }
        pJS.tmp.pushing = false;
      }
    }

  };
```

[the library's GitHub page](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/)

this is what i tried to complete what i need:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/particles.js@2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function () {
            console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
        });

        pJS.fn.modes.pushParticles = function (nb, pos) {

            pJS.tmp.pushing = true;

            // limit of the particles
            // this is used to limit the number of particles by calclating the canvas view
            var particlesLimit = Math.floor(pJS.canvas.el.width / 20);

            // each click adds 4 particles, so we remove 4 ones if there was more than limit
            if (pJS.particles.array.length > particlesLimit) {
                pJS.particles.array.shift();
                pJS.particles.array.shift();
                pJS.particles.array.shift();
                pJS.particles.array.shift();
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
                pJS.particles.array.push(
                    new pJS.fn.particle(
                        pJS.particles.color,
                        pJS.particles.opacity.value,
                        {
                            'x': pos ? pos.pos_x : Math.random() * pJS.canvas.w,
                            'y': pos ? pos.pos_y : Math.random() * pJS.canvas.h
                        }
                    )
                )
                if (i == nb - 1) {
                    if (!pJS.particles.move.enable) {
                        pJS.fn.particlesDraw();
                    }
                    pJS.tmp.pushing = false;
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Just assign a new function?

Comment: i tried it but suddenly it doesn't work, i added what i tried to the quesion

Comment: have you tried to override the pushFunction by assigning it to something like `alert('hello world');' and testing to see if that works?

Comment: Yes, you can overwrite an object property (which is what your target function is). In your example you might need to wait to do the reassignment within the `particlesJS.load` callback though.

Comment: if not then the function is simply not accessible due to encapsulation, basically this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108235/1046690